# Doctrine 2 toArray() method until we have traits?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, toarray

I **really** need a way to cast my entity to an Array. I know can do it manually but doing to on each entity is painfull, more working with relationship will not be easy.

How do you do? Have you implemented anything like that?

Comment: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_class_methods` to find the getters:

```
function toArray($object)
{
    $result = array();
    $methods = get_class_methods($object);
    foreach($methods as $method) {
        if ('get' == substr($method, 0, 3)) {
            $result[substr($method, 3)] = $object->$method();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: mm but what about relationships?

Comment: If the method return an object, use recursion.

Comment: yeah I know, I mean, but the problem is on infinite loops because of bidirectionnal relationships

Comment: Just add an array with the class names of the enties that you have passed and only do the recursive part if you haven't already visited that class.